# Cannot Import Difflib in python. How can I solve?

Tags: python, difflib

I am trying to use difflib but it's giving an import error. Can someone please help? 
Here is the traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "difflib.py", line 1, in <module>
    from difflib import SequenceMatcher
ImportError: cannot import name SequenceMatcher
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me your Python file is named `difflib.py`.  Don't do that.  It confuses the import system.

Comment: Did you happen to name your test program `difflib.py`?

Comment: @Kevin : Bingo !! Your powers worked :P
Stupid me :/

Comment: @anmol_uppal: Phrase [borrowed from Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/29/10109789.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to not name the source file `difflib.py` since in such case Python takes that instead of the actually desired `difflib`.

(Since the question was solved in the comments and no answer has been posted, inspired by a [relevant meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) I'm adding this answer to make the question complete. I'm not trying to get credit for [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1340389/kevin)'s or [BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427416/brenbarn)'s solution and I'm posting it as a *community wiki* answer.)